# Open a Specified VPN Connection dialogue using powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell, azure-virtual-network

I am trying to open a VPN connection dialogue using powershell. In my case rasdial and rasphone both are not working however clicking on the VPN name and then clicking on connect is working. Its the same clicking on network in the task manager and then clicking on VPN name which prompts a windows like -

[image]

want to do this using powershell

Answer (score 1):

I've checked a bit internally. This is currently not possible:

1. rasdial does not work with cert-based authentication, which Azure P2S VPN uses. And it typically could not be used to invoke the connection window.
2. The current Windows PowerShell only supports creating VPN profile, does not support invoking connection.

Thanks,
Yushun [MSFT]